# symbol lookup error undefined symbol

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I am using a JD2XX which  is a Java native interface port of Future Technology Devices International (FTDI) D2XX direct USB driver. I installed the libftd2xx1.0.4 drivers on ubuntu 11.10 then created and compiled a dynamic link library and obtained a jd2xx.so file. I load that on the java side using

```
static{
System.load("/home/user/NetBeansProjects/JD2XX-JNIdll2/dist/jd2xx.so");
}
```

When executing the program I am getting the following error:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin/java: symbol lookup error: /home/user/NetBeansProjects/JD2XX-JNIdll2/dist/jd2xx.so: undefined symbol: FT_ListDevices
Java Result: 127
```

Any hints what could be causing that? It all worked fine under windows using mingw.

Comment: @mre This is Linux, where the file path separator is '/'. There is no file path separator problem here.